# Affect a theme to a view page

Tags: views, theming

So, I create a view page that list the webform results, and I want to affect the administration theme to this page, How ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check [admin_theme](https://drupal.org/project/admin_theme) module. This will allow you to set custom pages in admin theme.